# Getting started with Cocos2d with ios (Sample Program issues)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i have downloaded cocos2d lib and added that to m xcode using terminal.
now according to the tutorial [Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial)

i want a hello world program to just understand the basic working of the cocoS2d.
i have create new program and then select the option as shown in the [image]

then i build the program and its gives me the following error
[image]

Can anyone help me regarding this issue>
thanks in advance for Good replies